# Track users that opened browser via app on Google Analytics

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, analytics

How can I track in Google Analytics users from my app that were redirected to my site (that "open with" feature on Android)?
I've tried to see by Source/Medium on GA360 but no success.
Any tip?

Answer (score 0):

You have to append [UTMs parameters](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033863) to the URL in your app so you can see in Google Analytics relative source and medium.

Example:

```
https://www.example.com/page.html?utm_source=MyApplication&utm_medium=App
```

And in Google Analytics you will see the `source / medium` **MyApplication / App** instead of `(direct) / (none)`.